# FluentLayout and control Min/Max Height

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

Is there a way to define a min/max height of UI element with FluentLayout?

My situation is like this:
[image]

Black UIView must be atleast 50px high. If anyone of it's child controls (Red UIView or BigTextUILabel) exceedes that 50px - it must stretch to accomodate its content.

If I define constraints:

```
blackView.Above(Table),
blackView.Height().GreaterThanOrEqualTo(50),
blackView.Height().GreaterThanOrEqualTo().HeightOf(redView)
```

blackView will stretch over whole screen (if table is empty). On the other hand if I change constraints:

```
blackView.Above(Table),
blackView.Height().GreaterThanOrEqualTo(50),
blackView.Height().EqualTo().HeightOf(redView)
```

redView will be stretched so the height of the red wiew (in this example) is equal to the height of the black view. So the First and Second UILabels wont be in the center of black UIView.

I couldn't find any examples on Priority or FullHeightOf. So to tell you the truth I don't know how it works.

Comment: Even though you have gone to a lot of effort writing this question (thank you!), I'm not entirely sure what the problem you are seeing is... If the problem is just stopping "black" from filling the screen, then you could just add a constraint on the Table to stop it disappearing? Maybe, consider either adding a complete code sample to the question or also read up on what FullHeightOf is https://github.com/slodge/Cirrious.FluentLayout/blob/9f6ecda117d67384bcb2840c0d949b6eeecee76a/Cirrious.FluentLayout/AdvancedFluentLayoutExtensions.cs#L118 and what Priority is on http://apple.co/1L3hRMR

Comment: Actually there are two problems, 1. stopping black from filling the screen. 2. Red have to be in the middle of the black (vertically) and high enough to fit it's own content.  I don't know which constraint to add to the Table because Table should be the one to stretch its height. If I put GreaterThanOrEqual constraint to the Table I could end up in part of black not showing (if bigtext UILabel is really big)

Comment: To make it more clear: red and black shoud stretch to accomodate it's content and nothing more. Black should be atleast 50px high. If Red is less than 50px high it should be in the middle of the black (vertically). Table should stretch to fill screen.

Comment: Sorry - those comments are hard to read - make me dizzy reading them! Sorry!

Comment: hahahaha ... ok np. Thanx anyway.

Comment: I solved it. but honestly I don't know what went wrong. The problem was in Black stretching too much so I played a bit with SetContentCompressionResistancePriority and SetContentHuggingPriority but it got me nowhere. So I copied bit by bit of my code in new class - and it started working. It puzzles me because I was cleaning and rebuilding my project as well as restarting VS. Probably some simulator or cache error.

Comment: I found what was causing a problem. For reusing purposes I have my view  consist of several UI objects who are inherited from UIView. If you initialize your constraints in constructor of UIView everything works fine. If on the other hand, you initialize constraints in overriden method UpdateConstraints UI goes berserk.